# VBA: Problems with Application.CountIf

Tags: vba, excel, countif

I have a stupid problem and don't know why..

I want to Import some values from another workbook.

Procedure:

-Open the other Workbook (Source)

-Get the needed Data Range.

-Copy the Data

-Get the number of appearances of node* to make the target Table ready.

-Switch to the target Table and get also the node appearances.

-Expand the target table.

-Paste the data.

My Problem:
It only gets the CountIf Value from Sorce table..

Below some Information:

```
Sub import_kundenform()

Dim LR As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim ActRow As Integer

actwb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
actsh = ActiveSheet.Name

fName = Application _
.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")

If fName = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fName)
startCell = 19
wb.Activate
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("B1:B" & LR)
wb.Sheets(1).Range("A7:L" & LR).Copy
ival = Application.CountIf(rng, "node*")
Workbooks(actwb).Worksheets(actsh).Activate

ival2 = Application.CountIf(rng, "node*")
If ival > ival2 Then
    ActRow = ival - ival2 + startCell
    Range("A20:A" & ActRow).EntireRow.Insert
ElseIf ival < ival2 Then
    ActRow = ival2 - ival + startCell
    Range("A20:A" & ActRow).EntireRow.Insert
End If
Workbooks(actwb).Sheets(actsh).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

If there are any information you need to know please let me know.

I hope you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> wb.Activate
> LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
>
> Set rng = Range("B1:B" & LR)
> wb.Sheets(1).Range("A7:L" & LR).Copy
> ival = Application.CountIf(rng, "node*")
>
> Workbooks(actwb).Worksheets(actsh).Activate
> ival2 = Application.CountIf(rng, "node*")
> If ival > ival2 Then
> ```

Both `ival` and `ival2` were calculated from the same range `rng`. Activating another workbook or worksheet will not change the `rng` range variable.

You wanted to get `ival2` from the same range on another wb/ws after activating it, try

```
 ival2 = Application.CountIf(Range(rng.Address), "node*")
 '                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Which will now refer to the same range but in the Active worksheet.

However, it is *highly recommended* to drop using the `Activate` stuff altogether and work always with *fully qualified ranges*.

```
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fName)
  startCell = 19
   'wb.Activate    ' <----------drop this
  With wb.Sheets(1)
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Set rng = .Range("B1:B" & LR)
    .Range("A7:L" & LR).Copy
    ival = Application.CountIf(rng, "node*")
  End With

  'Workbooks(actwb).Worksheets(actsh).Activate      ' <----------drop this
  With Workbooks(actwb).Worksheets(actsh)
    ival2 = Application.CountIf(.Range(rng.Address), "node*")
    If ival > ival2 Then
      ActRow = ival - ival2 + startCell
      .Range("A20:A" & ActRow).EntireRow.Insert
    ElseIf ival < ival2 Then
      ActRow = ival2 - ival + startCell
      .Range("A20:A" & ActRow).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will do it in the future :) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Kalain you are welcome. glad to know that it helped :)